# OOPS implementation

Tags: c#, oop

I have `Car`, `smartEngine` and `turboEngine` Class. Both `smartEngine` and `turboEngine` class have `start()` method. How will you implement it, So that it can be enhanced in the future if required. Also asked to write complete code and questions regarding the code.

Comment: the important thing to remember is that a car can carry more than one engine in the boot

Answer (score 1):

I will create `IEngine` interface:

```
interface IEngine
{
    void Start();
}
```

And both classes must inherit from this interface and then you can implement `Start` method for both classes:

```
public class SmartEngine : IEngine
{
      ...
      public void Start() { Console.WriteLine("SmartEngine"); } 
      ...
}

public class TurboEngine : IEngine 
{
      ...
      public void Start() { Console.WriteLine("TurboEngine"); } 
      ...
}
```

By the way, I don't know how you have implemented `Car` class, but there are two options depending on how many engine a car can carry. If it can carry onle one of them, then you just need one property with the `IEngine` type. But, if it can carry more than one, then you need to declare both of them in `Car` class:

```
 public IEngine engine;  // Car has an Engine
```

or

```
 public SmartEngine smartEngine;  
 public TurboEngine turboEngine;
```

As a side note, it is important to follow [naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002(v=vs.110).aspx). Always use **PascalCasing** for class names and method names.

Answer (score 0):

You can create **interface IEngine** that can be used in Car class (or elsewhere, where details of engine implementation has no meaning).

You can also create **abstract BaseEngine class** (that, of course, implements IEngine). This base class encapsulates common engine logic and eliminates code duplication. Many different engines (like **SmartEngine** and **TurboEngine**) can share same functionality using BaseEngine as base class. *If some engine has totally different behavior, then just use iterface and implement brand new engine class.*

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents car engine.
/// </summary>
public interface IEngine
{
    void Start();
}

/// <summary>
/// Implement base behavior for different engine implementations.
/// For example: Model property can be common for all your engines.
/// </summary>
public abstract class BaseEngine : IEngine
{
    protected BaseEngine(string model)
    {
        if (model == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        Model = model;
    }        

    public abstract void Start();

    public string Model { get; private set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Implement smart engine.
/// </summary>
public class SmartEngine : BaseEngine
{
    public SmartEngine(string model) : base(model) { }

    public override void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SmartEngine {0} started.", Model);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Implement turbo engine.
/// </summary>
public class TurboEngine : BaseEngine
{
    public TurboEngine(string model) : base(model) { }

    public override void Start()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TurboEngine {0} started.", Model);
    }
}
```